# How Do I Make A Previous and next Button synchronized For A Slideshow In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, slide

I don't get why when I click the forward button everything is ok. When I click the previous button everything is ok. but when I mix the two the 1st number is random I think.

```html
    <body>
        <button id="back"> &lt; </button>
        <img  name="name" width="400px"; height="500px;">
        <button id="forward"> ></button>
        <script>
        
        
            var i = 0; //starting point
            var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"]; 
            var forward = document.getElementById("forward");
            var back = document.getElementById("back"); 
            
            function next(){
                
                document.name.src = images[i];
                
                if(i < images.length - 1){
                       i++; 
                   }else i = 0; 
                
            }
            
            
        function before(){
            
            document.name.src = images[i];
            
            if(i == 0){
                i = images.length-1; 
            } else{
                i--;
            } 
        }
            
            
            
        forward.onclick = function(){ next()};
         back.onclick = function(){before()};   
            
            
         </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you add the code as snippet sections so we can run a preview of your code

Comment: I did it (I think). this is my first time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the new value **before** changing `i`.

With your current logic if you start by pressing > it will show image 0 and set the counter to 1. Then it doesn't matter which button you press, it will show image 1 before changing the value.

You need to assign it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You put `document.name.src = images[i];` before calculating index. You probably want that done *after*. This way the picture reflects yours *previous* button click and not the the current one.